# Hijacking the login page of Moodle

Tags: php, authorization, moodle

I'm creating an auth plugin for Moodle which is based on a token in a cookie which is created by another application. The Idea is that if the token in the cookie is not valid or missing a special custom site is displayed instead of the login site of Moodle. If the authentication was successful, the user should be redirected directly to a course page.

In the Moodle documentation for auth plugins there is the option to hook the loading of the login page to inject some content but it seems that there's no way to fully control what is rendered.

So how can I replace all the content of the default login site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the loginpage_hook function to either display a complete error page or to redirect to another page that will do this.

Take a look at [auth/cas](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/auth/cas/auth.php#l91) for an example of this in operation.

Comment: For some reason it wasn't working for the first time I tried the hook. It is working now. Thank you!